# Code in Python Idle edit won't run in shell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Python 3.8 and Windows. This is my code but when I click run it does nothing in the shell, :

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
import import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
source=open("C:\DATA ANALYSIS OPTIMIZATION\TrumpForbesRichestAmericans.csv")
data = np.genfromtxt(source, dtype=None, delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
print(data.head(5))
print(data.rank.describe())
print(data)
```

Comment: "Click run" where exactly? What do you mean by "the shell" here? To most readers, this suggests a terminal-like interactive session on a Unix-like system, where there is no "Run" and no "clicks" on anything.

Comment: Tangentially, use a raw string around Windows path names, or double the backslashes.